# C# - FrameworkElement.FindName returns null

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatemplate

I spent the past one hour trying to figure this out. I have a `CheckBox` inside `DataGrid` as follows:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
        <CheckBox Name="chkall" Content="Select All" Checked="chkall_Checked" Unchecked="chkall_Unchecked"/>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Tag="{Binding Path=id}" x:Name="chksingle"  Checked="chksingle_Checked" Unchecked="chksingle_Unchecked"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

As you can see I am trying to check and uncheck the `CheckBox`es inside `DataGrid` rows when the `CheckBox` in the header is checked or unchecked. This is the code where I am trying to retrieve the `CheckBox` and mark it as checked:

```
private void chkall_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var r in userDG.Items)
    {
        DataGridRow row =(DataGridRow)userDG.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(r);
        FrameworkElement FW_element = userDG.Columns[0].GetCellContent(row);
        FW_element.ApplyTemplate();
        var checkbox = FW_element.FindName("chksingle") as CheckBox;
        checkbox.IsChecked = false;
    }
}
```

I have already tried `RegisterName()` method and I've tried `VisualTreeHelper` but nothing works.

This line always returns `null`:

```
var checkbox = FW_element.FindName("chksingle") as CheckBox;
```

Here is a *WPF visualizer* screenshot for my `FrameworkElement` where I can clearly see the checkbox I am trying to find:

[image: WPF visualizer screenshot of FrameworkElement]

Please tell me what am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that a `DataTemplate` is a name scope boundary, that is the templated element (a `ContentPresenter` in this case) or any of it's ancestors are not aware of named elements defined inside the template. In order to find a named element inside the template you need to use  the [`DataTemplate.FindName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead (inherited from `FrameworkTemplate`). Notice that it takes two parameters instead of one, the second one being the templated element. This should do the trick for you:

```
private void chkall_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var r in userDG.Items)
    {
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)userDG.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(r);
        FrameworkElement FW_element = userDG.Columns[0].GetCellContent(row);
        //We use the CellTemplate defined on the column to find the CheckBox
        var checkbox = ((DataGridTemplateColumn)userDG.Columns[0]).CellTemplate.FindName("chksingle", FW_element) as CheckBox;
        checkbox.IsChecked = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The CheckBox does not exist in the scope that the Row knows. It is not a Direct child of its Template.

You need to use the static class VisualTreeHelper to drill down from the row to find an instance of type CheckBox, and compare against its x:Name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
FrameworkElement FW_element = userDG.Columns[0].GetCellContent(row);
CheckBox checkbox = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(FW_element, 0) as CheckBox;
```